# Windows 7 user specific logon script

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, script, batch-file

I've got a Windows 7 laptop here. At my internship we use network accounts, except when they need to use a laptop external from our locations. We've got an account, but we have a Sierra Wireless Broadband chip in there.

Now we need to disable the wifi when they login with that specific account, but it needs to be enabled when that account logs out.

Has anyone got an idea? We've already tried creating a script with gpedit and Windows Task scheduler. In the batchfile is `netsh interface set interface "Wireless Interface" disabled`, but that didn't work. It looked like the user-account won't run the script.

Answer (score 0):

As @treintje wrote you need admin privileges to disable network adapters.
What you rather can do is make the wireless adapter unusable by making a task in task scheduler that disconnects the wireless network whenever it tries to connect.

Set it only to run when the user is logged in (and of course select the user that should not be able to connect wirelessly)

As trigger use this setting:

[image: Task Scheduler Trigger]

As action you need to add a batch script with this content:

```
NETSH wlan disconnect
```

Comment: Let me know if you need more info as how to get this going and I'll edit my answer to include more info. Br.

Answer (score -1):

Administrator rights are required to enable/disable network interfaces. Without sufficient rights, I get the following error message: "An interface with this name is not registered with the router."

Instead of disabling the wireless network adapter you could try to disconnect it.

```
netsh wlan disconnect
netsh wlan connect Name
```

*Name* refers to the name of the network profile that is used to connect to a specific wireless network. The network profile name is set to the SSID by default.